# Freemarker template cursor positioning at a particular point

Tags: java, string, freemarker

I have a template like this

```
<#---->         FF MSMAA                  003/99/99
<#---->         FF MSAON
<#---->         FF MSTAS                  9968
<#---->         FF MSTRA                  9968
<#list 0..nDDFJESize as x><#--
-->         <#if x%5 == 0>PO<#else>PP</#if> NDDFJE                 ${NDDFJE[x]?substring(0, 41)}<#if x%4 == 0>                        ERR115 ACCT NOT FOUND<#else></#if>
</#list>
<#list 0..mSUALSize as x><#--
-->         FF MSUAL               01 ${MSUAL[x]?substring(2)}
</#list>
<#---->         FF MSINA
<#---->         FF MSAOF
```

I used a trick to limit the string using substring, but the issue is that I can't determine the length of that string in run-time and it could be anything.

```
         FF MSMAA                  003/99/99
         FF MSAON
         FF MSTAS                  9968
         FF MSTRA                  9968
         PO NDDFJE                 4110112898/000000010000///Goalkeeper Xfer                        ERR115 ACCT NOT FOUND
         PP NDDFJE                 6113855517/000000005000///Goalkeeper Xfer
         PP NDDFJE                 6110000789/000000025000///Goalkeeper Xfer
         PP NDDFJE                 6113855494/000000030000///Goalkeeper Xfer
         PP NDDFJE                 6110000654/000000002500///Goalkeeper Xfer                        ERR115 ACCT NOT FOUND
         PO NDDFJE                 0115025906/000000072500///Goalkeeper Cred
         FF MSUAL               01 10/4110112898/6//08262019
         FF MSUAL               01 10/6110000456/6//08272019
         FF MSUAL               01 10/6110000789/6//08272019
         FF MSINA
         FF MSAOF
```

I want to have those error msgs starting at a particular point. I tried searching on the net but I got nothing that I am looking for. Before down-voting it, please give me the reason to do so! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the way around it. Made changes in Java and added variable length of white spaces left bound to make the String of consistent length.

`tempString = String.format("%-65s", tempString);`

Where tempString is what I add in root!